# Como receber uma notificação sempre que houver registro novo em uma tabela do banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, tabela-banco-de-dados, notificação

Preciso receber uma notificação sempre que houver um registro novo em uma determinada tabela do banco de dados, o que posso fazer para receber ?

1. Se eu usar um *trigger* no MySQL não vai funcionar quando eu mudar de banco de dados.
2. Se eu fizer uma requisição Ajax a cada determinado intervalo, acabo por fazer requisições desnecessárias.
3. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Obviamente uma solução desse tipo não faz parte de nenhum padrão SQL, então não há motivo para descartar uma solução específica usando uma trigger.

Comment: Quem precisa ser notificado, tudo mundo? E tudo bem se tiver um atraso na notificação? Parece uma tarefa para o cron.

Comment: bfavaretto, apenas 10% de todos os cadastrados (500 pessoas)  serão notificados, não há problemas se houver atrasos.

Comment: @user737, não se esqueça de aceitar uma resposta se fôr a "resposta certa". Assim a pessoa que respondeu recebe também alguns pontos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Defina uma arquitetura

Se você quer algo portável entre bancos você deverá fazer em seu sistema. 
Crie um padrão de projeto como:
VIEW ---> Serviço ----> DAO (ou Repository).

O DAO seria o responsável por saber se determinado registro foi ou não atualizado, seja por cache que poderia ser utilizado com Ajax ou por WebSocket onde uma notificação seria enviada.

---

#### Exibindo em View : WebSocket

Você poderia utilizar HTML5 + WebSocket para enviar os valores para a tela. Toda vez que um registro for atualizado no DAO (ou Repository), uma notificação seria enviada para a view.

A abordagem do WebSocket funciona com o servidor enviando a notificação para a página, inverso de uma notificação ajax onde a página busca o valor.

---

#### Exibindo em View : Ajax

Ao utilizar o Ajax você não precisa ir toda hora ao banco de dados para saber se houve alteração.

Você poderia ter esse valor cacheado em memória, caso houvesse alguma alteração, seria retornado o valor novo. Se não houvesse alteração, você não retorna nada. Seria algo como, você enviaria a data da última consulta: 10/10/10 10h10min. Caso o valor do cache fosse o mesmo, não precisa ir ao banco. Caso o valor do cache indicasse que o horário do registro mais novo fosse de 10/10/10 10h15min aí você buscaria a informação nova.

Uma chamada Ajax não causaria essa sobrecarga no servidor uma vez que estaríamos mexendo com valor cacheado.

---

#### Conclusão

Cada abordagem tem sua vantagem e desvantagem. Basta você escolher a que melhor se encaixa no perfil do seu projeto.

**Atenção: Caso o valor em questão seja atualizado constantemente, independente da abordagem, haverá um grande tráfego de dados na rede.**

Comment: Obrigado uaiHebert. :)